# For all $A, B \in\Bbb Z$, if $A\mid B$ and $B\mid A$, then $A =B$.

Tags: solution-verification

I know this is a simple question, but I am struggling a bit. What I have so far is. Let $A, B$ be arbitrary elements in $\Bbb Z$ and assume $A\mid B$ and $B\mid A$ is true.
$A=B \Rightarrow \dfrac{A}{B}=\dfrac{B}{B} \Rightarrow  \dfrac{A}{B} =1$  and  $A=B \Rightarrow \dfrac{A}{A}=\dfrac{B}{A}\Rightarrow 1=\dfrac{B}{A}$. Therefore $A$ and $B$ are elements in the set and are equal to each other.

Does this prove the statement?

Comment: $A=1, B=-1{}{}$?

Comment: or more generally $A=-B\not=0$

Comment: @KentaS I want to prove that A=1 and B=1

Comment: or that they are the same

Comment: @bhhha1232 I am saying your statement is false.

Comment: @KentaS and that is because it is the set of integers?

Comment: @bhhha1232 That is because I found a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

We have $a,b\in\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}$. If $a\mid b$ then $a=rb$ for some $r\in\Bbb Z$. If $b\mid a$ then $b=sa$ for some $s\in\Bbb Z$. Then $a=rb=rsa\Rightarrow rs=1\Rightarrow r,s=\pm1$, so $a=\pm b$.

Comment: Does this answer your question?